# opacity not getting added in ie8 for generated html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an animation code where opacity gets added to the div tag...
but at the same time the opacity is not getting added in IE8
providing my code below...
can you guys tell me why its not getting added...

```
function soccerMatches(matches) {
    var $profile = $('.color'),
        matchesIds = [],
        $soccers;

    $.each(matches, function(i, match) {
        matchesIds.push('#profile' + match.title);
    });

    $soccers = $(matchesIds.join(', '));

    **$profile.not($soccers).css('opacity', 0.33);**
    $soccers.css('opacity', 1);

}
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @FelipeMiosso@FelipeMiosso: thannks for your reply...i am using "jquery": "1.11",

Answer (score 2):

IE8 does not support "opacity"

Comment: Shouldn't jQuery fix that ?

Comment: @adeneo It depends on jQuery version

Comment: @FelipeMiosso - That's true, but in jQ versions that support IE8, opacity shouldn't be an issue, should it ?

Comment: @FelipeMiosso: thannks for your reply...i am using "jquery": "1.11",

Comment: Regardless of jQuery, you're still setting the CSS opacity, which is not supported.

Comment: @Nick thanks for your reply...what is the solution now